# How to convert wav file to spectrogram for tensorflowjs with columnTruncateLength: 232 and numFramesPerSpectrogram: 43?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

i'm trying to use tensorflowjs speech recognition in offline mode. online mode using microphone is working fine. but for offline mode i'm not able to find any reliable library for converting wav/mp3 file to spectrogram according to the required specs of array as 
ffttsize:1024 , 
columnTruncateLength: 232, 
numFramesPerSpectrogram: 43.

All libraries like spectrogram.js that i tried dont have those conversin options. while tensorlfowjs speech clearly mentions to have following specs for spectrograph tensor

```
const mic = await tf.data.microphone({
  fftSize: 1024,
  columnTruncateLength: 232,
  numFramesPerSpectrogram: 43,
  sampleRateHz:44100,
  includeSpectrogram: true,
  includeWaveform: true
});
```

Getting error as Error: tensor4d() requires shape to be provided when `values` are a flat array in following

```
await recognizer.ensureModelLoaded();
    var audiocaptcha = await response.buffer();
    fs.writeFile("./afterverify.mp3", audiocaptcha, function (err) {
        if (err) {}
    });
    var bufferNewSamples =  new Float32Array(audiocaptcha);

    const buffersliced = bufferNewSamples.slice(0,bufferNewSamples .length-(bufferNewSamples .length%9976));
    const xtensor = tf.tensor(bufferNewSamples).reshape([-1, 
...recognizer.modelInputShape().slice(1)]);
```

got this error after slicing and correcting to tensor

```
output.scores
[ Float32Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  Float32Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  Float32Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  Float32Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  Float32Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
score for word '_background_noise_' = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
score for word '_unknown_' = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
score for word 'down' = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
score for word 'eight' = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
score for word 'five' = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
score for word 'four' = undefined
score for word 'go' = undefined
score for word 'left' = undefined
score for word 'nine' = undefined
score for word 'no' = undefined
score for word 'one' = undefined
score for word 'right' = undefined
score for word 'seven' = undefined
score for word 'six' = undefined
score for word 'stop' = undefined
score for word 'three' = undefined
score for word 'two' = undefined
score for word 'up' = undefined
score for word 'yes' = undefined
score for word 'zero' = undefined
```

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The only requirement when working with offline recognition is to have an input tensor of shape `[null, 43, 232, 1]`.

1 - Read the wav file and get the array of data

```
var spectrogram = require('spectrogram');

var spectro = Spectrogram(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  audio: {
    enable: false
  }
});

var audioContext = new AudioContext();

readWavFile() {
return new Promise(resove => {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'audio.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function() {
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    resolve(buffer)
  });
};
request.send()
})

}

const buffer = await readWavFile()
```

The same thing can be done without using the third party library. 2 options are possible.

- Read the file using `<input type="file">`. In that case, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317866/read-samples-from-wav-file) shows how to get the typedarray.
- Serve and read the wav file using a http request

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "file.wav", true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onload = function () {
  var arrayBuffer = req.response;
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Float32Array(arrayBuffer);
  }
};

req.send(null);
```

2- convert the buffer to typedarray

```
const data = Float32Array(buffer)
```

3- convert the array to a tensor using the shape of the speech recognition model

```
const x = tf.tensor(
   data).reshape([-1, ...recognizer.modelInputShape().slice(1));
```

If the latter commands fails, it means that the data does not have the shape needed for the model. The tensor needs to be sliced to have the appropriate shape or the recording made should respect the `fft` and other parameters.

Comment: the arraybuffer contains the signal in time domain not the spectogram @edkeveked

Comment: I think that what the OP meant was to get the tensor data from the signal wav file

Comment: yes, this is exactly what your answer addresses. But it partially solves his problem. The question indicated by his title "How to convert wav file to spectrogram for tensorflowjs with columnTruncateLength: 232 and numFramesPerSpectrogram: 43?"

Comment: Why is the answer incomplete ? If it does not solve your issue, maybe you can consider open a new thread with your question